# Error when running Docker Compose in Visual Studio project for RabbitMQ container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gsxsolutions/rmq-nano/) in a container via  Visual Studio project.
I took the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/gsx-solutions/rmq-win/blob/master/Dockerfile.3.7.7) placed it in a subfolder in my project directory and updated the `docker_compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service1:
    blahblah
  service2:
    blahblah
  the_rabbitmq_service:
    image: messagingqueue
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: SubFolderName\Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - ../some/path:c:\somepath
```

When I try to build my project, it goes out to run the relevant services and pull images it does not have. The first two services succeed (as they previously did) but the new one I added tries for a bit and then gives me this error:

> 1>Service 'the_rabbitmq_service' failed to build: The command
>   'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
>   $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
>   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
>   [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri
>   $env:rabbit_download_url -OutFile rabbitmq.zip ;     Expand-Archive
>   -Path .\rabbitmq.zip -DestinationPath "c:\" ;     Remove-Item -Force rabbitmq.zip;     Rename-Item c:\rabbitmq_server-$env:RMQ_VERSION
>   c:\rabbitmq' returned a non-zero code: 1

I know it's not much to go on but I'm hoping that someone out there has any insight into my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker_compose.yml` file does not only have to build from a `Dockerfile`. Instead, you can include the image from which it can do a pull as well.

Therefore, what worked for me is instead of pointing to the problematic `Dockerfile`, I simply did:

```
  the_rabbitmq_service:
    image: gsxsolutions/rmq-nano:3.7.7
    ports: 
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - ../some/path:c:\somepath
```

That worked for me.